# Select2 v4.0 and extra css

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

It seems that I'm not able to sort out how to add extra css to the generated container. I was scrolling through the sourcecode and found something about CssContainer, but didn't got it to work.

Any ideas someone since nothing is mentioned in the docs...?

Kind regards,
Dwight

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to add the extra css to select2 ...

```
$("#myselect").select2({ width: '100%' });     

$("#myselect").select2({
      containerCss : {width: '100%'},
      containerCssClass: "your class" 
});
```

if you want to add or remove the classes on select2 use this code after you initialize the select2

```
$($("#myselect").select2()).addClass("className");
$($("#myselect").select2()).removeClass("className");
```

[see the documentation](http://select2.github.io/select2/) for more information

Comment: Sorry, but you are linking to the 3.5.1 release, I'm referring to the v4.0 releases...

Comment: have you tried these options? are those not present in v4.0?

Comment: Don't think they made it yet in v4 RC2, about 2 weeks ago some support was added but don't know how it works :(

This seemed to work, but don't like it... it feels and looks very hacky
$('#myselect').data('select2').$container.addClass('className');